# Regular Expression question

Tags: c#, .net, regex

RegexBuddy shows the matches are OK, but in C# when I try use replace, a semicolon and a curly bracket  are not replaced.

The expression I am using is the following:

```
@"({\\)(.+?)(}+)|(\s?\\)(.+?)(\b)|}$"
```

and the input text (rtf) is included in the screenshot.
This the code:

```
Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\\b([\s\S]+?)\\b0");
MatchCollection matches = reg2.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string output = reg.Replace(match.Value, "");
    MessageBox.Show(output);
}
```

[image: RegexBuddy screenshot]

Comment: Also post the actual code you are trying to do the replace with.

Comment: The code you posted isn't using the regex you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to match nested structures with regular expressions. Look at your screenshot: in the first line there are three opening braces and one closing brace, in your third line you have one opening and two closing braces etc.

While .NET does provide ways to do nested pattern matching with regexes, your regex is not using them (and it's extremely mystifying to me what exactly you're hoping to achieve).

You most certainly need to use a different way to parse RTF files; unfortunately I don't know whether the .NET libraries provide an RTF parser.

Comment: Tim, I'm trying to clean text from RTF tags. I almost succeeded except for those two characters (;}) which appear only if I add color to the RTF text.

Comment: Please don't use regular expressions for this. A regex that happens to work on one RTF file is guaranteed to fail on any number of other RTF files. Why not open the file in Word and save as text? You can even do that programmatically.

Comment: I'm doing this because I need to extract formatted segments like italic, bold, etc and use it somewhere else in a Flash Actionscript file.

Comment: This is frustrating. I've been working on this problem for almost two days. I tried several ways but no success so far. I need to extract formatted text from a RichTextBox and tag these segements with html tags so that I can restore format when I use then in Flash.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question: How can I convert formatted text from a RichTextBox into HTML using C#? Regex definitely is a dead end here.